# TypeError using Telnet.write()

Tags: python, python-3.x, telnet

I have the following code:

```
try:
    tn = Telnet(host, str(port))
except Exception as e:
    print("Connection cannot be established", e)
    traceback.print_exc()
print("You are connected")
tn.write('command?'+'\r\n')
while True:
    line = tn.read_until("\n")
```

When I run this code on machine X everything is working just fine, but when when I try to run the same code on a different machine I end up with the following error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File
 "C:/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/terminalManager/terminalManager.py", line 50, in <module>
 terminalManager()
 File
"C:/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/terminalManager/terminalManager.py", line 16, in __init__
self.connect(terminalBganIp, terminalBganPort)
File "C:/Users/admin/Documents/Projects/terminalManager/terminalManager.py", line 34, in connect
tn.write('AT_IGPS?'+'\r\n')
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python\Python3.6.1\lib\telnetlib.py", line 287, in write
if IAC in buffer:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes
```

Am I doing something wrong or is the second machine messing with me?

**EDIT:**

When i used IDLE debugger on my second machine everything is working. it seems it is not working when running it normally, is there anything i can do to resolve this?

Comment: As the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/telnetlib.html#telnetlib.Telnet.write) indicates, the `Telnet.write()` function expects to be passed an argument that is a byte string, not a string—so you need to convert the `'AT_IGPS?'+'\r\n'` string, which isn't shown in your code, into one. Are both machines running the same version of Python (this likely changed between Python 2 and 3)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't believe that the same code is working for you on another machine with the same python version.

Your issue is exactly what the Exception says it is `TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes`. You need to provide `bytes` to `tn.write` instead of a `string`.

You can convert your string into bytes via `encode`:

```
command = "command?" + "\r\n"
tn.write(command.encode("ascii"))
```

Edit: Well, someone beat me to it :D

Comment: Tied it, the problem is still the same... i get to the "you are connected" and than everything freeze

Comment: I find this very strange running the idle debugger step by step i get everything working...

Comment: Does this behavior occur every time? Maybe it is a problem with the telnet server executing your command. Try `for _ in range(max_tries)` instead of `while True` to abort your program at some point.

Comment: [Working](http://imgur.com/a/QNm5i)  , [Not Working](http://imgur.com/a/XrBTO) - just to show that it works on machine 1 and not on machine 2 while both connected to the same device.

Comment: Does the connection eventually close? If so you could use `read_all` which would basically do the same thing.

Have you tried a system telnet client to check whether it works from the machine where it's not working with python? 

Which python version are you using? In your error message it's 3.6, but in your screenshot it's 2.7. Don't mix the same code with different python versions (at least not across 2 and 3).

Try using `read_some` and printing throughout to check whether you get any data at all.
As suggested by martineau, python2: string, python3: byte-string. That's prob the issue

Comment: the code is written in 2.7 that is why i run it in idle 2.7, i am able to connect to the terminal via putty or cmd telnet and do everything normally, I do not have use for read_some() or read_all() as i need to read lines until i find what i need

Comment: Well, `read_some` and `read_all` would be for debugging purposes, to check whether the command returns anything at all. Your problem now is that you can't find a line-break `\n` in the command-output correct? Without further information about the connection and the expected return value, it's rather hard (for me) to give advice, especially since I'm not too familiar with telnet. Your `working` picture indicates that the connection closes eventually, try `read_all` and post the output here (redacted if you want).

Comment: I have tried to change to read_some / read all, still the same result, wont get any data. program is frozen at "you are connected"

Comment: Thank you for the help i have found the problem. adding time.sleep(0.1) solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try to do:

```
tn.write(('command?'+'\r\n').encode())
```

Usually sockets work over bytes not strings, the error could be related to that, hope this can help.

Comment: Tried that also... not working as it should. it was working fine the other day... today everything broke and i did not change a single line of code.